# Issue while making HTTPs request from Hololens to Azure OCR service

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

We are migrating an application from UWP to Unity, in which we are trying to access azure OCR services from Unity . While making a https request from unity we are getting the below error
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

```
Exception thrown at 0x7787A0CB in EyeTrackingCus01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x156DEEC0.
Exception thrown at 0x7787A0CB in EyeTrackingCus01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x156DF048.
Exception thrown at 0x7787A0CB in EyeTrackingCus01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x031AE3C8.
The thread 0x1410 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The code snippet used is as follows:

```
static async Task MakeOCRRequest(string imageFilePath)
{
    Debug.Log("MakeOCRRequest Function Called");
                        
    string subscriptionKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string endpoint = “https://hololensxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/”;
    // the OCR method endpoint
    string uriBase = endpoint + "vision/v2.1/ocr";
    string requestParameters = "language=unk&detectOrientation=true";
    string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;
    byte[] data = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);
    Debug.Log("Image File Path: "+imageFilePath);
    Debug.Log("Image File Size: "+data.Length.ToString());
    Debug.Log("Response: Image Converted into byte Array");
                                      
    try
    {                                               
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                                                      
        Debug.Log("Request object:" + req);
                                                      
        req.Method = "POST";                          
        req.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";                                   
        req.ContentLength = data.Length;                                      
        req.Expect = "application/json";
        req.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        req.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                                                      
        Debug.Log("Before the Response");
                                                      
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponseAsync().Result;

        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                                                      
        Debug.Log("Response:"+json);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.log("Error" + e.Message);
    }                               
}
```

Comment: In general have you tried rather using [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)?

Comment: Just want to mention that the original code was written in UWP and hence had the HTTPWebRequest present as part of the code and while migration to unity it gives the error. But we have changed to Unity web request and now the request go through